# EXTJS4 Window Event

Tags: javascript, html, events, extjs4

I've been asked to re-write a file using the EXTJS4 framework. The legacy file is written in EXTJS2. I have found a point in a view file from which I can start but even after reading Sencha's documentation, following the examples and tutorials I am pretty stumped on how to get started.

Essentially all I want to achieve at the moment is having a window panel appear when this div is clicked.

This following code would be where the event would start;

```
<td class="width200 align_left" style="width:213px !important">
    <div style="float:right"><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="#" title="<?= t('Select Product')?>" id="showProductWindowB" onclick="selectFreeGift=false;showProductWindowB(); return false;"><img style="vertical-align:middle" src="/www/icons/modify.gif" alt="<?= t('Select Product')?>"/></a></div>        
</td>
```

The window doesn't need to contain anything right now either, I just need to make it so one appears. From there I can add to it.

So if anyone could show me how I would get this started or give me some helpful info I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you going wrong?
You can easily create and open a window:

```
<a href="javascript:openWindow();">Click!</a>

<script>
var yourWindow;
openWindow = function () {
    if (!yourWindow) {
        yourWindow = Ext.widget('window', {
            title: 'Hello',
            height: 200,
            width: 400,
            closeable: true,
            closeAction: 'hide'
        });
    }
    yourWindow.show();
};
</script>
```

See this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/laurenzonneveld/tDqJZ/)

Comment: I hadn't removed the old resources includes. Noob mistake. It caused lots of conflicts. This is perfect, just what I needed to get going. Thanks!